# Find most identical string in string collection

Tags: c#, string, collections

I have a List with all system font names. Here is a part of the List:

```
Arial
Calibri
Times New Roman
```

My problem is: I have 16 ASCII characters (2 bytes) of the fontname with the fontface (Bold, Italic, Regular)

```
Calibri Bold
Arial Bold Itali
Times New Roman
```

How can I get the fontname (ex. Arial) from the list if I have a string (ex. Arial Bold Itali)

Hope someone can help me or give me advice.

Answer:
I did it vice-versa. Bet this can me done more efficient but it works for now.

```
foreach (string fn in FontHelper.FontNames)
        {
          if (Font.FontName.Contains(fn))
          {
            fontname = fn;
            break;
          }
        }
```

Comment: why do you not take these comma separated??

Comment: This paper compares many options: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pradeepr/papers/ijcai03.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can also use start with.

```
string str = "Arial Bold Itali";

if(str.StrartWith("Arial"))
{
   return str;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use Levenshtein distance. It's a nice thing to find most identical strings. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) you can read about it, also you can find some algorithms to find that distance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [.contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method

```
string str = "Arial Bold Itali";

if(str.contains("Arial"))
{
   return str;
}
```

Comment: I don't think he has `Arial` known before hand .. it would be then a if for every font name

Comment: The situation is vice versa: *How can I get the fontname (ex. Arial) from the list if I have a string (ex. Arial Bold Itali)*.

Comment: I tried this FontNames.Where(x => x.Contains(Font.FontName)).First(); where FontNames is my List of Fontnames (Arial) and Font.FontName is (Arial Bold Itali)

Answer (score 1):

My advice, would be to strip-out the font modifiers before you do your matching. I assume there's only a few different kinds of modifiers fonts can have.

```
var fontToFind = "Arial Bold Itali";

fontToFind = fontToFind.Replace("Bold", "").Replace("Itali", "").Trim();

//Do search
```

Comment: Might not be good enough. What if the font face name contains the substring "Bold"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "most identical" means that one is the prefix of the other, you can do something like this:

```
var fonts = new[] { "Arial", "Calibri", "Times New Roman" };

var input = new[] { "Calibri Bold", "Arial Bold Itali", "Times New Roman" };

var result = input.Select(item => fonts.Single(font => item.StartsWith(font)));
// result == { "Calibri", "Arial", "Times New Roman" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of heuristic -- for example, stripping out any "Bold" and "Italic" suffixes (I don't really know what else could be encountered).

That can be done with a regex:

```
var str = "Arial Bold Italic";
var fontName = Regex.Replace(str, "((Bold|Italic)\\s*)*$", String.Empty);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/4HTsb)**.

Plus, you can very easily extend this to strip more suffixes such as "Oblique".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Striping "Bold", "Italic", ... doesn't work very easily. I only have 16 characters, most of the times I end up with xxxxxxxxxxxxx Bo, xxxxxxxxxxxx Ita. when the fontname is more then 16 character, I don't have the full font name..

Comment: @Wixon: OK, what about making the regex more involved? [Example](http://ideone.com/HEBK1).